# How to display the source code of a website in a console application?

Tags: c++, c, web

I guess this question is somewhat wide but I'm trying to create a C console application (on windows os) that lets the user input the website address and the app will output the source code on the screen.

The second one was for me to traverse to the site source code to extract some contents.

Given that I know how to code in C (or C++), know how to parse user's input to valid web address and that I know how to traverse to a file,
**is there any C library out there that lets me do the part of getting data over a website, like it's source code (HTML)?**

Many thanks! :)

Update: C++ libraries also accpeted, but please show example of how to do the part of extracting it's source code or a link perhaps, thank you
 :)

Comment: You mean the source code, as in, say, PHP code, or the HTML of a page?

Comment: of course the HTML of a page since a PHP code can't be viewed on the client part :)

Comment: WRT @Luchian's comment, for the latter there is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/), for the former there is nothing

Comment: You never know, there have been weirder questions here on SO... besides, when you say "source code", you usually mean "source code", not its output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Or, for C++, [curlpp](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/).

Comment: It's a library which you can use pretty easily in your code (see documentation)

Comment: Thanks! I see that this is the solution but do I need to install cURL before I could use libcurl?

Comment: @Raven, no, you just need to have libcurl, not curl.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any `C` standard library to fetch the website content. But I guess you need something like `wget`. For example, try the following:

```
wget http://stackoverflow.com/
```

The website content will get stored in `index.html`.

OTOH, you can explore `libcurl` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libcurl).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something with telnet. If you connect to a server with telnet on port 80, type

```
GET /<webpage.htm> HTTP/1.1
```

and press enter twice, you'll get the complete HTTP reply and the html source code of the webpage.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try maybe:

system("URL2FILE filesource filedestination");

http://www.chami.com/free/url2file_wincon.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a small program , i made to extract & save/write Facebook account source code in a text file. You can change it with your need ( you can change "http://www.facebook.com" with "http://www.google.com/").. Also remember to link wininet.a (library) to your project. Hope it will help :)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>
fstream fs_obj;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fs_obj.open("temp.txt",ios::out | ios::app);  
  HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0 );
  HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA( hInternet, "www.facebook.com", 80, " "," ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0 ); //enter url here
  HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequestA( hConnection, "GET", "/", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0 );

  char buf[ 2048 ] ; string total;
  HttpSendRequestA( hData, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 ) ;
  DWORD bytesRead = 0 ;
  DWORD totalBytesRead = 0 ;

  while( InternetReadFile( hData, buf, 2000, &bytesRead ) && bytesRead != 0 )
  {
    buf[ bytesRead ] = 0 ; // insert the null terminator.
    total=total+buf;
    printf( "%d bytes read\n", bytesRead ) ;

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead ;
  }

  fs_obj<<total<<"\n--------------------end---------------------\n";
  fs_obj.close();
  printf( "\n\n END -- %d bytes read\n", bytesRead ) ;
  printf( "\n\n END -- %d TOTAL bytes read\n", totalBytesRead ) ;
  cout<<total; //it will print source code in console window
  cout<<endl<<total<<endl; //it will save source code to (temp.txt) file
  InternetCloseHandle( hData ) ;
  InternetCloseHandle( hConnection ) ;
  InternetCloseHandle( hInternet ) ;
  system("pause");
}
```

Rename temp.txt with temp.html , open it with browser you will get that webpage.